# Как задать цвета всем повторяющимся значениям чисел в таблице в javascript?

Tags: javascript

Все повторы значений должны выделяться одинаковым цветом для значения.Например: если число "2" встречается несколько раз, то все они выделяются одним цветом (например, зеленым),если встречается несколько раз число“5”,то оно выделяется другим цветом(например, красным) и т.д..Числа без повторов остаются черными.

Comment: А что не получается - подсчитать количество повторов?

Comment: нет, выделить все повторяющиеся двойки зеленым, все повторяющиеся пятерки красным и т.д. Не знаю, как реализовать

Comment: числа заданы рандомно и выведены в таблице

Comment: ну так приложите вашу таблицу и как вы числа создаете к вопросу, без вашего кода, можно только очень общий ответ написать

Answer (score 1):

Любая задача должна разбиваться на более-менее элементарные этапы (по-умному - декомпозиция).

В данном случае можно предложить такой подход:

```
Создать словарь (map, dictionary), содержащий пары число-количество

Пройти по ячейкам, для каждого числа посчитав количество повторов

Создать массив или словарь, устанавливающий соответствие количество повторов - цвет

Обойти ячейки, уже задавая цвет, соответствующий числу
```

Comment: скорее всего не нужно привязывать цвет к числу, а просто брать из массива

Comment: Да, разумно. Количество повторов вряд ли будет идти плотно, чтобы индексы массива напрямую соответствовали им, поэтому может быть лучше опять же словарь

Answer (score 1):

```js
const COLORS = ['tomato', 'pink', 'orange'];


let table = document.querySelector('table');
let tds = table.querySelectorAll('td');

let tdInfoMap = Array.from(tds).reduce((map, td) => {
  let value = td.textContent;
  let info = map.get(value) || [];

  if (!info.length) {
    map.set(value, info);
  }

  info.push(td);

  return map;
}, new Map())

Array.from(tdInfoMap.values()).forEach((tdAll, index) => {
  if (tdAll.length > 1) {
    tdAll.forEach(td => td.style.background = COLORS[index])
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: спасибо большое